# Numerical integration - $\int_{-1}^{1} f(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods

I'm currently studying numerical integration, and ive come across a question i'd like help answering.

We are given an integration rule as follows:

$I(f)=\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)dx = \frac{2}{3} [f(x_1)+f(x_2)+f(x_3)]$

Find $x_1,x_2,x_3$ such that this rule is accurate for polynomials of degrees 3 or less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 3 points you should see that, if $f(x) = a x^3 + bx^2 +c x + d$, then $I(f) = 2 d + \frac{2 b}{3}$ So you need to solve $\frac{2}{3} ( a( x_1^3 + x_2^3 + x_3^3) + b(x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^3) +c(x_1 + x_2 + x_3) + 3d ) = 2 d + \frac{2 b}{3}$, or:

$\frac{2}{3} ( x_1^3 + x_2^3 + x_3^3)  = 0$

$\frac{2}{3} ( x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2)  = \frac{2}{3}$

$\frac{2}{3} ( x_1 + x_2 + x_3)  = 0$

Solving you could guess that $x_2=0$ and $x_1 = - x_3$ achieving the desired result $x_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$, what is the exact value of $I(f)$? And what is the value estimated by the proposed rule? The latter depends on $x_1,x_2,x_3$ and you should find $x_1,x_2,x_3$ so that the estimate is always correct ...

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't quite get this with three points, but maybe this will help.

First let's look at $x$ and $x^3$. These have integral zero since they are odd. This means you need to prove it for polynomials of the type $$a_2 x^2 + a_0$$

These are even functions, so $$\int_{-1}^1 (a_2x^2 + a_0) = 2 \int_0^1 (a_2x^2 + a_0) dx$$

And a quick computation for $x^2$ yields:
$$\int_0^1 x^2 dx = \frac{1}{3} = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2.$$

Thus we see that $\int_{-1}^1 (a_2x^2 + a_0) = 2 \left( a_2\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2 + a_0\right)$

Now if $f(x) = a_3 x^3 + a_2 x^2 + a_1 x + a_0$ then $$f\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right) + f\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right) = 2 a_2 \frac{1}{3} + 2 a_0 = \int_{-1}^1 f(x) dx$$